# My app size of React native app is too large after installation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I ve made a react native app. the release apk size is 28. That is ok, but I was shoked whwn saw the storage size 62 mb. I am despareately searching for solution, please help me, I have to pass my work soon((

Comment: Can you clarify what `28` refers to (what units)? What have you tried so far? Have you done any research on "decreasing the size of a react native-based android app"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `android/app/build.gradle` try setting `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture` to `true`. This will create separate apk files for each architecture you support which do not include libraries for all other architectures. I could shrink the installation size with that method from 70 to 38 megabyte.